# Regex to capture only a character from a date

Tags: regex, file-rename

I have a bunch of file names starting with a date in the form of

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

and I want to get rid of the `-`

The problem is I don't want other `-` affects the search/replace. For example, many files are named like:

```
2002-01-24 This-is-a-file-001002
```

But I want to replace just the `-` part in the date.
I can't figure out what regular expression I can use for this.

I tried `^.{1,10}` to capture the date but I don't know how to capture the `-` within the date.

Comment: `s/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/\1\2\3/`?

Comment: What is the tool you are using?

Comment: A better finder renamer on mac but I'm open to other options to batch rename some files

Comment: Try with `'s/^\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1\2\3/'`. It would still be helpful to see how you are using the regex.